# Auto rotate whirly globe in Android

Tags: android

How can I rotate the 3D globe provided by WhirlyGlobe SDK in Android. I've tried this but it is not working.

```
mGlobeController.getGlobeView().animate();
```

and also this

```
globe.setRotation(100.0f);
```

I've seen the globe rotating automatically in iOS, anybody know how to achieve this in Android?

Comment: Looks like you found our github Issues page, so I'll answer there rather than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `setAutoRotate(interval,degrees)` in `GlobeController`